# Generate a + 1 if I Choose example informative of a Combo box

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Private TotalAct3 As Integer

Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then InfoList1
End Sub

Sub InfoList1()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Non-Informative"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Informative"
    ComboBox1.AddItem ""
    ComboBox1.ListRows = 3
    
        If ComboBox1.AddItem = "Informative" Then
            TotalAct3 = TotalAct3 + 1
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want to do? I think your are looking for `If ComboBox1= "Informative" Then .....`

Comment: You need to use the ComboBox1 click event to check if the value is "Informative" and then do a +1 to whatever you are doing

Comment: ` If ComboBox1.Value = "Informative" Then TotalAct3 = TotalAct3 + 1`... You can use that code line in the 'ComboBox1' `Change` event...